# mySQL: multiple sources for table: split or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

If a table has multiple sources (each source contains a different type of data), is it best practice to split that table into multiple tabes (with the necessary foreign keys) or do you nevertheless fit it into one table.

simplified example:

- want to make a table containing client info
- 2 sources of data, all csv files:

  1. static data, almost never changes (e.g. start of the relationship, headquarters, etc)
  2. revenue data which changes monthly

In this case do you go for one table (e.g. t_client) containing both static and revenue data, which you then update monthly? Or do you make multiple tables: one with the static data (e.g. t_client_info) and one with the variable info (t_client_revenue, update monthly) and link them?

just want to know what is best practice

Comment: 2 tables is the way to go. Otherwise, you are just repeating static data for each revenue... record.

Comment: ok, makes sense

Comment: I wouldn't create fields according to their frequency of change. At the beginning one table is enough and other tables are created according to their relational value (eg headquarders is a table at its own (id,name), with foreign key head_id to t_client, start is a t_client field, etc)